# Django app is not connecting with remote database

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django app running on hosting server. I am using postgres database which is running on different server. **The app is working properly in my local machine** but in hosting server, the app is running but any functionality is not working which is associated with database. For example, user can not authenticated while login even the username and password is correct.
I am receiving a error saying "could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
**My settings for database**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'IP_ADDRESS',
        'PORT': 'PORT',
    }
}
```

**N:B I have given permission to the postgres database. I can access the db from local machine**

---

**Django version 2.2.5**

Comment: any errors so far?

Comment: No error is raised in server.

Comment: Are sure that Django takes the actual DB values?

Comment: and are you sure that your server can reach your database server?

Comment: bro I am not sure if it can't reach the database or any other issues. I can accessed while it is in my local machine

Comment: is there any way to see internal server log that appeared in local server using 'runserver' ?

Comment: When you set your local settings to the remote db, what is the error you get when you call `python manage.py migrate` or similar?

Comment: are you able to ping the database server from you django app server?

Comment: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "IP_ADDRESS" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following database configuration snippet in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '***.***.***.***',
        'PORT': '5432'
    },
}
```

Replace *** with your database credentials
Make sure you have already installed `psycopg2` through package manager like pip

- Also ensure that your local postgrSQL db server's settings  were made to access it from outside your localhost if not then try with below settings.

  - In postgresql.conf file Change `listen_addresses  =  “localhost”`  to  `“ * ”`
  - In pg_hba.conf file add this 2 lines at the end of file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                  md5
host    all             all              ::/0                       md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
host    replication     all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
host    replication     all             ::/0                 md5
```

- Finally restart the db service of postgresql

Comment: I am edited the config file like this but it still throws error. "could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: @TanveerHasan  I have added more settings  for pg_hba.conf  in the answer section. Please try with it. These changes will effect after the restart of the database service.

Comment: @TanveerHasan also try with disabling the firewall of the machine on which database server is running. If it is successful then add the rule for the port 5432 in firewall's inbound rule group.

Comment: Make sure that the "listen_addresses" is not commented out.

Comment: This was working But now it is not working