Django connecting localhost PgSQL but not to remote DB (AWS RDS)
I have a Django project which is using the PostgreSQL as DB service. In local DB, everything is working fine.
But when I try to connect to PostgreSQL instance in AWS RDS, it does not connect. The credentials to connect are correct and I'm able to connect to DB using command line, Dbeaver (a DB tool) and TablePlus (another DB tool)
Local DB configs
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "NAME": 'my_db_name',
        "USER": 'my_user',
        "PASSWORD": 'my_password',
        "HOST": 'localhost',
        "PORT": '5432',
    }
}

Remote DB configs
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "NAME": 'my_db_name',
        "USER": 'my_user',
        "PASSWORD": 'my_password',
        "HOST": 'xxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        "PORT": '5432',
    }
}

Am I missing anything here?

I even tried django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 as mentioned in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984929/django-app-is-not-connecting-with-remote-database

enable django DEBUG=True and please show me the error with remote db settings.i think it will print out error and then we  can take it from there

I set Debug = True in settings.py. There is no error

then how do you know its not connecting?? do you see any error ? please provide details on error that you see. just saying it does not connect does not mark the scope of porblem.

python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate commands do not work, they just don't print anything at all.
